# Installing Ruby on Rails on a new Mac OS Sierra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew, rbenv

I am learning to code and trying to make the move for a Rails project from a cloud dev environment to a local one on my Mac with OS Sierra. However, I am having trouble setting up my ruby version and installing rails.

I have installed Homebrew which I used to install rbenv. Using rbenv I have installed ruby 2.4.0 and set it to local and global. I can see it in .rbenv/versions, however when I check my ruby version I still get 2.0.0

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
```

When I try and install Rails I get the following;

```
$ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

I am not sure how I utilize the rbenv ruby version in my system to then install rails.

Comment: Did you use sudo at some point?  Installing rbenv? ruby 2.4.0?  You should NEVER use `sudo` for that. It looks `gem install` is trying to install in your system ruby, which you don't want to touch.  *I can see it in .rbenv/versions,*--That isn't a path.  What's the part before .rbenv?

Comment: *you can install rbenv and ruby-build using the Homebrew package*. -- Did you install ruby-build?  Did you do this: `rbenv init`.  In other words, did you follow the instructions exactly?  Pasting your whole terminal session into your question would allow people to see where you made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add `rbenv` to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile  
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then source it:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then you can use the `rbenv` command:

```
# install a Ruby version:
$ rbenv install <version>

# show versions currently installed and indicate current version
$ rbenv versions

# set ruby version for a specific dir
$ rbenv local <version>

# set ruby version globally
$ rbenv global <version>

# list all available versions:
$ rbenv install -l
```

The `rbenv` command is used to install, switch between versions, etc.

Comment: Did the rbenv install instructions for Mac OSX really leave all that out?

Comment: @7stud: Which part of the instructions are you not finding? It's all right here: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I entered the second echo command and then sourced it. After running both of those it seems to be working.